# django admin redirect after a successful login

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django=1.6.1.

Currently in my project, the admin system takes me to admin dashboard after a successful admin login (i.e: localhost:8000/admin/). From here I can visit most of my apps like users, categories, groups etc..

90% of the time I want to visit the users admin page (i.e localhost:8000/admin/my_project/users/). thus I am trying to find a way to redirect the admin login to admin users page rather than the dashboard. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is the right way to tackle this issue but this is how I have solved my problem.

I created a subclass of `AdminSite` called `CustomAdminSite` and overwritten the `login()` to accept a redirect url using the REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME(i.e using the 'next' hidden field option).

```
class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):
    @never_cache
    def login(self, request, extra_context=None):
        """
        Displays the login form for the given HttpRequest.
        """
        from django.contrib.auth.views import login
        context = {
            'title': _('Log in'),
            'app_path': request.get_full_path(),
            REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME: settings.ADMIN_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL,
        }
        context.update(extra_context or {})

        defaults = {
            'extra_context': context,
            'current_app': self.name,
            'authentication_form': self.login_form or AdminAuthenticationForm,
            'template_name': self.login_template or 'admin/login.html',
        }
        return login(request, **defaults)  

site = CustomAdminSite()
```

in urls.py

```
admin.site.login = path.to.custom.site.login
```

in settings.py

```
ADMIN_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/my_project/users/'
```

P.S: please let me know if there is a better way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently on Django (and since version 1.8) you can [reverse your admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) to redirect to any admin page.

For example:

- The url you want to redirect to: `/admin/my_project/users/`
- The reference: `href="{% url 'admin:app_list' 'app_name' %}`
- The implementation: `href="{% url 'admin:app_list' 'users' %}`

Assuming you only have one model `MyUser` inside your `users` app, you can go directly into the admin list view of that model.

- Reference: `href="{% url 'admin:app_label_model_name_changelist' %}`
- Implementation: `href="{% url 'admin:users_myuser_changelist' %}`

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by overriding the 'admin:index' url (the url named 'index' within admin namespace).

Comment: FYI this not a way but only idea, that's why I am downvoted, if it would be severline lines of code I would upvote