# Django 1.7 admin for non-staff users

Tags: django-admin, django-1.7

On a previous project (with Django 1.5), I used a customized Django admin site to provide access to a limited subset of models for non-staff users. I used the excellent explanation provided [here](http://blog.tryolabs.com/2012/06/18/django-administration-interface-non-staff-users/). This was working like a charm.

For a new project, I'm using Django 1.7 and I've learnt that check_for_test_cookie() is deprecated. However, just commenting it out does not seem to provide the required functionality. I get an error when I try to log in on my user_admin site, both with staff and non-staff accounts. The error message I'm getting "Please correct the error below" does not give me any extra clues.

Any suggestions on how to make this work in Django 1.7? My code is given below.

myapp/user_admin.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

ERROR_MESSAGE = ugettext_lazy("Please enter the correct %(username)s and password "
        "for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.")
class UserAdminAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    """
    Same as Django's AdminAuthenticationForm but allows to login
    any user who is not staff.
    """
    this_is_the_login_form = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                                initial=1,
                                error_messages={'required': ugettext_lazy(
                                "Please log in again, because your session has"
                                " expired.")})

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        message = ERROR_MESSAGE

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username,
            password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                if u'@' in username:
                    # Mistakenly entered e-mail address instead of username?
                    # Look it up.
                    try:
                        user = User.objects.get(email=username)
                    except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):
                        # Nothing to do here, moving along.
                        pass
                    else:
                        if user.check_password(password):
                            message = _("Your e-mail address is not your "
                                        "username."
                                        " Try '%s' instead.") % user.username
                raise forms.ValidationError(message)
            # Removed check for is_staff here!
            elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError(message)
        #self.check_for_test_cookie()
        return self.cleaned_data

class UserAdmin(AdminSite):

    login_form = UserAdminAuthenticationForm

    def has_permission(self, request):
        """
        Removed check for is_staff.
        """
        return request.user.is_active

user_admin_site = UserAdmin(name='usersadmin')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.user_admin import user_admin_site
from mypapp.models import *
from myapp.admin import *

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.register(mystaffmodel,mystaffmodel_admin)

user_admin_site.register(mynonstaffmodel,mynonstaffmodel_admin)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(user_admin_site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: After some trial and error, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584935/django-admin-redirect-after-a-succesful-login) solution which did the trick. It seemed to have something to do with the redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form must be like the following

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission


class UserAdminAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):    
        if not user.is_active:    
            raise forms.ValidationError(    
                _("This account is inactive."),    
               code='inactive',    
            )
```

It will enough to work your code. :-)