# Django admin.site.urls only accessible to superuser (The admin login page only accessible to superuser)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

What i want is to limit access to the django admin login page to only the superuser. Meaning if you are not the superuser, and try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` - you should be redirected to 404 page , something like that.The means or the custom view to perform this authentication is the challenge. Please somebody assist me with a hint on how to do it?

```
  urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', my_custom_function,name="check_if_superuser"),


     # when somebody hits this url pattern , he/she should be taken to the 
     # function above for checking if superuser befor being redirected to 
     # django admin login page
 ]
```

and in my `views.py` i have the following function that does the authentication

```
    def  my_custom_function(request):
         if request.user.is_superuser():
            #... redirect to django admin login page

         else:
             # return render(404_page)
```

yeah something like that.

Comment: what's the problem this sounds fine

Comment: where can i find the or redirect to the  django admin login template

Comment: When you log out, how you can access /admin urls for admin login? by default django redirect you to login urls when you try to access /admin

Comment: i should perform  the checking only for logged in users and see whether they are superuser or not

Comment: Here check out this post you can do something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584935/django-admin-redirect-after-a-successful-login

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If the user is not logged in, how would you know they were a superuser? And if they are logged in, why would they need access to the login page?

Comment: Well he doesn't want logged in users being able to access the admin login page, because it isn't secure against brute force attacks. How do i make the django admin only viewable to super users, this is including the admin login. I'm trying to overide the django admin login with AllAuth.

Answer (score 2):

By default, django admin allows login for superuser or stuff user only. So, it is kind of safe to have a admin login panel. Also, if you want to restrict that login path, I think its best to put a firewall on that particular route. So that only whitelisted IPs can access it. You can use NGINX for this, and configuration should be something like this:

```
location /admin {
  # block one workstation
  deny    192.168.1.1;
  # allow anyone in 192.168.1.0/24
  allow   192.168.1.0/24;
  # drop rest of the world 
  deny    all;
}
```

This [article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/) could be helpful with the configuration.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this does not seem to answer the question at all. (Not that the question makes much sense, anyway.)

Comment: well, IMHO, this kind of restrictions(when a user should access admin site) should be done in NGINX, Apache etc, not in the django application. Its true, the answer does not provide anything to do with normal user restriction from django side. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there might be a catch 22 in the described scenario.

1. To check user rights there should be a logged in user
2. If you put check only on available users - is_superuser and show 404:

- logged in, non super_user will receive 404
- not logged in visitor can go to admin page

2. If you add check whether user is logged in and if not show 404 as well:

- no one can login from admin page, unless logged in somewhere else and got to admin afterwards

Both scenarios sound inconsistent to me. I think what you are trying to achieve is intended to be done by Django framework in a slightly different way.

---

There is `has_permission()` in `AdminSite` class in `django.contrib.admin.sites` which

> Return True if the given HttpRequest has permission to view *at least one* page in the admin site

and by default returns `request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff`
If you change it in your admin.py, only active superusers will be able to utilize admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin

def has_superuser_permission(request):
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_superuser

# Only active superuser can access root admin site (default)
admin.site.has_permission = has_superuser_permission
```

And even logged in non-sups will be shown message about insufficient rights and prompted to re-login